# .on('click') not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, html-select

I've got the following snippet of code on my webpage:

```
$('#activityFilter option').on('click', function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("tableFilter").value;
    searchTable(opts, text);
    $('.spotRow').first().click();
});
```

In my index.html file, there is a drop-down `<select id="activityFilter">`, and I'm trying to call `searchTable` whenever the user selects a new item on this drop-down. However, it seems like the `.on('click')` is never triggered in Chrome or Safari. However, it's working fine in Firefox and IE. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not really what that event is for. Why not use [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)?

Comment: use onchange on the select id. Click may not fire properly in all browsers so it is not a good idea to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the jQuery's [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of attaching an event

Comment: The `click` method is just a wrapper for `on('click', ...)`. So this won't make any difference.